# Is it correct and natural to say "a country is closed" meaning it's difficult to get into it?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Is it correct and natural to say *a country is closed* meaning it's difficult to get into it? For example:

> North Korea is one of the most **closed** countries in the world.

If not, what would a native English speaker say instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed [means](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/closed):

> having or forming a boundary or barrier

Therefore, this definition fits your sentence since there is a barrier to get into the country. As a native speaker, I would use your sentence.

Another option:

> North Korea is one of the most **inaccessible** countries in the world.